# Maximum Browser Upload Size

Tags: browser, http, upload

can someone tell me what the biggest file is I can upload with current browsers (in 1 HTTP request)?

I found this page http://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/pa98.htm but it seems to be older. Maybe newer Browsers can upload bigger files.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/10/wininet-internet-explorer-file-download-and-upload-maximum-size-limits.aspx) is a table summarizing the limits for various IE versions.

Answer (score 3):

There is no specific answer to this question, because RFC 2616 (HTTP 1.1) does not specify a maximum size for the data portion of the POST command and as such it is undefined behavior, left to the implementor.

when writing code that consumes HTTP, everything appears as a stream, so as far as the server and the browser are concerned, theres not really such a thing as length.

That said, the browser and the Web server stack almost always make choices on how much to limit post size. You will have to look at your server platform (IIS/Apache/NGinX, etc) to determine what it is for your environment. Runtimes like PHP and ASP.Net both implement limits as well. The primary motivation is as protection from dos attacks, which either consume bandwidth, hog CPU, or fill up your disk space. it would be trivial to just keep writing '1's to the stream and eventually fill up the servers disk were there not such a limit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Still I know that there are limitations on the client side as well. (as shown in user4186's comment) And those are the ones I am looking for.

Comment: that's definitely the case. the browser implements its own limitations. There's just no relation between that limit and the number of http requests. I would also expect that since the limits on your (old) chart are in the 2-4GB range, that the client side is not the thing to consider when asking the question "can I upload this file?". The common server limits are generally less than 50MB as Techie007 points out (this is to prevent against Distributed DOS).